# Render Submitted Fields of a Form to Email with Title + Value

Tags: 8, forms

I have a quite complex form based on `\Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase` with many (partially nested) fields and want to send the full contents in an email on submit.

Currently I have

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{

   foreach ($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value) {
     if (!empty($form[$key]['#title']) && $key != 'images') {
       $values[$form[$key]['#title']->render()] = $value;
     }
   }
...
# later I will format the $values array as a HTML list
```

This would only show fields on the top-level of the form, but I have fields within groups.

Is there a nice and clean way to render all the field's values? Or do I have to iterate and parse manually over the `$form` array?

Could I even use a renderer for this?

EDIT:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {


    // ...

    $form['company'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
    ];

    $form['company']['nameofcompany'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t('Name of Company'),
    ];
```

To sum it up:

How can I iterate over all the fields, including those which are in containers and get the values + the label (not only the technical name)? Are there some nice helpers for this or do I have to do it all manually?

Comment: That code would not work and it doesn't make sense. Why do you need `$form[$key]['#title']` to access a value in `$form_state`? Furthermore, since `$form[$key]['#title']` is a string, it doesn't implement any `render()` method.

Comment: It would also help to see the code building the form. It's not clear what you mean by *groups* and if *fields* means *form elements*.

Comment: the code currently does work, #title is an object, I believe that's because the form is already built. My only problem is to iterate over all form elements, because they are nested in groups. I add some example code how the initial $form array is built.

Comment: Without seeing all the form elements, it's not possible to understand what you mean by *groups*. As for the shown code, it's sufficient to use `'nameofcompany'`, not what returned by `$this->t('Name of Company')`. You already have `$values['nameofcompany']`; you don't need `$values[$this->t('Name of Company')]` set to the same value.

Comment: I need the labels, not the internal names

Comment: I have edited the question - with groups I mean containers. See the sample code. Does this make it more clear? Let me know, if you have questions.

Comment: @apaderno I posted an answer ... but I am wondering if there is a nicer - not so low-level - way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with, I am just wondering if there is a more elegant way, than this "low-level" parsing

```
/**
 * Return an array with labels as keys, submitted values as values, based on the original form
 *
 * @param FormStateInterface $form_state
 * @return array
 */
private function generateLabelsWithValues(FormStateInterface $form_state): array {
  $form = $form_state->getCompleteForm();
  $result = $this->iterateAndAddValues($form, $form_state);
  return $result;
}

/**
 * Iterate over form or container and add up the values
 */
private function iterateAndAddValues(array $formOrContainer, FormStateInterface $form_state, array $result = []) {
  foreach ($formOrContainer as $key => $element) {
    if ($key[0] === '#' || $key === 'form_build_id' || $key === 'form_id' || $key === 'submit') {
      continue;
    }
    if ($element['#type'] === 'container' || $element['#type'] === 'fieldset') {
      $result = $this->iterateAndAddValues($element, $form_state, $result);
      continue;
    }

    if ($value = $form_state->getValue($key)) {
      $result[(string)$element['#title']] = $value;
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
```